# SQL Server 2005 Data Encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption

My requirement is that we have an Application "FinApp" which handles all Finance Related data of the Company.Current Audit Team has asked us to Encrypt data on production to enhance security.

I already have knowledge about standard SQL encryption with keys and all. Also we created a CLR Based Function so that the enc. keys are in application server and passed while calling, so that the DB Team cannot access data as well.

The thing is when we will run this on Production with close to 10-12 crores records will this kind of SQL work? Already using function calls in select query is working slow if a CLR Based Function or for that matter SQL Encryption is used. Has anyone done it?

```
"select encrypt(columna), encrypt(columnb), encrypt(columnc), encrypt(columnd) from mytableofhughnumbers"
```

We are of the view that performance would be severely hit. What alternative do we have if the data is huge and encryption is required? Database is sql server 2005.

Comment: If you can't trust your DBAs, you've got deeper issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an article for this

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-2005-database-encryption-step-by-step.aspx